# Login submit button unable to Reach [httpost]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Here I'm trying to create login page using asp.net MVC4 application, but unable to check the database data using `HttpPost`

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogIn(string returnUrl = "")
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return LogOut();
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public  bool ValidateUser(string UserID, string Password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(UserID) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(Password))
            return false;

        using (ntc_salesEntities context = new ntc_salesEntities())
        {
            var user = (from u in context.user_master
                        where String.Compare(u.UserID, UserID, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                              && String.Compare(u.Password, Password, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0
                         select u).FirstOrDefault();

            return user != null;
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(Models.user_master model, string returnUrl = "")
    {
       // if (ModelState.IsValid)
      //  {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserID,model.Password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.UserID,false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login details are wrong.");
            }
            return View(model);
       // }
    }
```

Login:

```
@model Loginusingmvc.Models.user_master

@{
   ViewBag.Title = "LogIn";
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
  }

@Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Login Failed, check details")

<div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", new { returnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post))
    {
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login Form</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(u=> u.UserID)</div>
        <div class="editor-field">@Html.TextBoxFor(u=> u.UserID)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u=> u.UserID)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">@Html.LabelFor(u=> u.Password)</div>
        <div  class="editor-field">@Html.PasswordFor(u=> u.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u=> u.Password)
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="Login" />

    </fieldset>
    }
</div>
```

Routing:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "LogIn", id =    
          UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: In your **Html.BeginForm** specify required parameter like this - **@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", new { returnUrl = Request.QueryString["returnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post))**

Comment: yes changed but still not working

Comment: Here you have post code of your view **login.cshtml**. Is it complete code or you have post just part of code ???

Comment: yes it my total code now i eidted my question please check it once

Comment: Everything seems perfect, Okay in your **Login** method add parameter like this - **public ActionResult Login(user_master model, string returnUrl = "")**... Here i have removed the word - "Model".

Comment: You haven't told us what error you are getting or how far you get...

Comment: Remove the attribute - [HttpPost] from **ValidateUser** method

Comment: I am not getng any error just unable to fire the button in post

Comment: yes i do stil nochange (Remove the attribute - [HttpPost] from ValidateUser)

Comment: Hi, could any any one help me for above solution if (Membership.ValidateUser(model.Username, model.Password) it says my username and password is not valid .. but I add a username and password into my table

Comment: i edit my question [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogIn(string returnUrl = "")
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return LogOut();
        }

        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    } it's working fine

Comment: Can you verify in which place you have a problem? Check post request in browser?

Comment: when i click on login button login event is fired but  here :Membership.ValidateUser(model.UserID,model.Password) it's not calling the validateuser action..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried in this way without using Memebership:

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(Models.user_master model, string returnUrl = "")
{

        if (ValidateUser(model.UserID,model.Password))
        {
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(model.UserID,false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Login details are wrong.");
        }
        return View(model);

}
```